Grouping adjacent documents in MongoDb by criteria
Having a documents collection ordered by field, I want to group documents by other field but only adjacent documents should be grouped. Like so:
[
  {order: 1, state: 'one'},
  {order: 2, state: 'one'},
  {order: 3, state: 'one'},
  {order: 4, state: 'two'},
  {order: 5, state: 'two'},
  {order: 6, state: 'one'},
  {order: 7, state: 'two'},
  {order: 8, state: 'three'},
  {order: 9, state: 'three'}
]

should result in:
[
  [
    {order: 1, state: 'one'},
    {order: 2, state: 'one'},
    {order: 3, state: 'one'}
  ],
  [
    {order: 4, state: 'two'},
    {order: 5, state: 'two'}
  ],
  [
    {order: 6, state: 'one'}
  ],
  [
    {order: 7, state: 'two'}
  ],
  [
    {order: 8, state: 'three'},
    {order: 9, state: 'three'}
  ]
]

Unfortunately I'm quite new to MongoDb so I have little to no idea even where to start from.
I suspect this can be achieved with some king of aggregation, but have no idea where to start from.
Tried $group with _id: null and $setWindowFields and bucketing, but with no success.

You can use the aggregate command to match against any field value, or sort into sets. See Aggregation Operations for more information and samples.

You'll need to $sort & $group all your documents and then use $reduce to create an array-of-arrays of objects.
For each sub-object, check whether it has to be added to the previous sub-array (when state is the same) or as a new sub-array with one doc (when state is different).
Note that this will not work if you have too many documents since each aggregation stage is limited to 100MB. So I hope you have some $match stage to apply before the first sort.
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: { order: 1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      docs: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$docs",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                // last value `state` is different or initial value
                $ne: [
                  {
                    $getField: {
                      field: "state",
                      input: { $last: { $last: "$$value" } }
                    }
                  },
                  "$$this.state"
                ]
              },
              then: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", [["$$this"]] ] },
              else: {
                $concatArrays: [
                  // take all except the last elements of the current
                  {
                    $slice: [
                      "$$value",
                      { $subtract: [{ $size: "$$value" }, 1] }
                    ]
                  },
                  // add this element to the last subarray
                  // and concat it to the previous
                  [ { $concatArrays: [ { $last: "$$value" }, ["$$this"] ] } ]
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // if you want all the groups in one result, remove this stage
    $unwind: "$docs"
  }
])

Mongo Playground - add/remove elements in the sample collection to see the behaviour for each step of the grouping. Note that each group/array has to be a value of a field in a document, you can't just have an array as a document.

Edit: If the size of the documents generated is too big for the aggregation $group stage, then you can do do it programmatically; which would have been trivial. Example, in Python:
from itertools import groupby 

lst = [...]  # your input docs combined into one list/cursor/iterable
final = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(lst, lambda e: e['state'])]
# final is as per your expected output

# or
results_cursor = db.collection.find({}, sort={"order": 1})
final = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(results_cursor, lambda e: e['state'])]


Reusing the idea I answered in another question, we can do the following in an aggregation pipeline:

use $setWindowFields to find the state in the previous document with $shift. We will name it prevState and use it to compare with state tp indicate if the current document is a start of "grouping"
compute the "grouping" using order in the window range of [unbounded, current] (i.e. find in the documents before and in the current document with a $max)
$group to group the documents

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "sortBy": {
        "order": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "prevState": {
          $shift: {
            output: "$state",
            by: -1,
            default: null
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "sortBy": {
        "order": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "grouping": {
          "$max": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $ne: [
                  "$state",
                  "$prevState"
                ]
              },
              "then": "$order",
              "else": -1
            }
          },
          "window": {
            "documents": [
              "unbounded",
              "current"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: "$grouping",
      docs: {
        $push: {
          order: "$order",
          state: "$state"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground
P.S. You could potentially avoid grouping all documents in an array field and the complicated processing on that array field. But you will still suffer from MongoDB 16MB document size if a single grouping contains too many records. You can skip the last $group stage and simply use the field grouping as the group indicator if this is an issue for you.

Was thinking of trying something similar, and this is much better +1 since setWindowFields doesn't put everything into one document at that stage! So this could work for very large collections without running into to the stage limits; excluding the last group but that's necessary for the output.
